# Return XML data from Nvarchar(MAX)

Tags: sql-server, xml, t-sql, xml-parsing

I need some help pulling data from a nvarchar(max) column storing XML data.

Here is sample data.

```
<ArrayOfstring xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/Arrays">
  <string>B1-10</string>
  <string>B2-20</string>
  <string>B2-20</string>
</ArrayOfstring>
```

I have tried this and only return NULL's then errors out to "XML parsing: line 1, character 2, illegal qualified name character"

```
SELECT cast(COLUMNNAME AS xml).value('/ArrayOfString[1]/String[1]', 'VARCHAR(MAX)')
FROM dbo.TABLENAME
```

I have tried numerous ideas off this awesome site and all seem to have the same result. What am I missing here? Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: not sure I understand why are you casting XML if you say the column stores XML type?

Comment: if you need XML data as relational, you may check this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38826788/read-value-from-a-complex-xml-structure-using-sql-server?rq=1

Comment: Just out of curiosity, have you tried first wrapping the value in a CAST AS VARCHAR(4000) to "down-cast" it?

Comment: I did try to "down-cast" with the same result. Thanks for the input.

Comment: I've frequently gotten this 'illegal character' error when trying to cast strings to xml. There's usually some (sometimes invisible) character in there.  I use REPLACE() to strip out the illegal characters, once I find them. Pasting into something like NotePad++ can help. Two examples I had were REPLACE(@v, CHAR(0), CHAR(32)) -- to eliminate trailing nulls (from a blob/binary column), and REPLACE(@v, '&#x7', '7') -- eliminate illegal xml character 7 ... some serialization layer put the &#7 in. So look for something like this.

Comment: Don't forget XML is case-sensitive. 'ArrayOfString' isn't the same as 'ArrayOfstring'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
;WITH XMLNAMESPACES(DEFAULT 'http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/Arrays', 
                    'http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance' AS i)
SELECT cast(COLUMNNAME AS xml).value('(/ArrayOfstring/string)[1]', 'VARCHAR(MAX)')
FROM dbo.TABLENAME
```

Comment: That did it. Thanks for all your help

Comment: Glad to hear! Please accept my answer if it was the correct solution for you. Thanks!